# How to make it shorter (Pythonic)?

Tags: python

I have to check a lot of worlds if they are in string... code looks like:

```
if "string_1" in var_string or "string_2" in var_string or "string_3" in var_string or "string_n" in var_string:
    do_something()
```

how to make it more readable and more clear?

Comment: regular expression, (but don't remember how to do it in python)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is one way:

```
words = ['string_1', 'string_2', ...]

if any(word in var_string for word in words):
    do_something()
```

Reference: [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any)

**Update:**

For completeness, if you want to execute the function only if *all* words are contained in the string, you can use [**`all()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) instead of `any()`.

Also note that this construct won't do any unnecessary computations as `any` will return if it encounters a `true` value and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) is used to create the Boolean values. So you also have some kind of *[short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)* that is normally used when evaluating Boolean expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
if re.search("string_1|string_2|string_n", var_strings): print True
```

The beauty of python regex it that it returns either a regex object (that gives informations on what matched) or None, that can be used as a "false" value in a test.

Answer (score 2):

With regex that would be:

```
import re
words = ['string_1', 'string_2', ...]

if re.search('|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in words]), var_string):
    blahblah
```

Comment: I nearly to upvoted because it's inventive and Felix Kling already got so many upvotes ;) But it fails if any of the strings contains regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at filter?

```
filter( lambda x: x in var_string, ["myString", "nextString"])
```

which then can be combined with map to get this

```
map( doSomething(), filter(lambda x: x in var_string, ["myString", "nextString"] ) )
```

EDIT:

of course that doesn't do what you want.  Go with the `any` solution.  For some reason I thought you wanted it done every time instead of just once.

Comment: Won't that execute `doSomething()` for any word that is in the string?

Comment: Yes.  Oh wait, he only wanted is done once, no?  Crap.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> string="word1testword2andword3last"
>>> c=re.compile("word1|word2|word3")
>>> c.search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7715d40>
>>> string="blahblah"
>>> c.search(string)
>>>
```

Comment: this appears less concise and less pythonic to my python eyes

Comment: Define Pythonic? What makes something Pythonic? The only concise statement above is re.compile and re.search. The rest are just showing output examples. Oh wait, the Python interpreter prompt might be blurring your Pythonic eyes...

Answer (score 0):

one more way to achieve this
`check = lambda a: any(y for y in ['string_%s'%x for x in xrange(0,10)] if y in a)`

`print check('hello string_1')`