# String.Contains in Python

Tags: python

I have a code like this...

```
if active == 1: // A flag which is set if a Site is Active
    for link in BeautifulSoup(content, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_key('href'):
           if 'MY_TEXT' in link['href'].upper(): //Check if the link has the string MY_TEXT in it. If it has print it and break the loop
               print link['href']
               break
```

Now, I want to improvize this code to check MY_TEXT1, MY_TEXT2 and MY_TEXT3 too. I do not want to write plenty of IF statements. Instead I did something like this

```
a = ['MY_TEXT1', 'MY_TEXT2', 'MY_TEXT3']

if active == 1: // A flag which is set if a Site is Active
    for link in BeautifulSoup(content, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_key('href'):
            for x in a:
                if link['href'].__contains__(x):
                    print link['href']
                    break
```

But this did not work. I mean no Syntax/Compile/Run-time error. No output either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not `if x in link['href'].upper()` as before?

Comment: My answer here might help you: [How to make it shorter (Pythonic)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600834/how-to-make-it-shorter-pythonic/3600855#3600855)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell us the input on which it does not work.

One obvious difference between the first version and the second is the lack of `.upper()` in the second. **Is this what's causing the problem?**

It is also unclear why you'd replace `in` with `__contains__`, but that should not matter either way.

Comment: You are correct! I missed out the upper() in version 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to write this would be to use `any()`:

```
    if link.has_key('href'):
        href = link['href'].upper()
        if any(x in href for x in a):
            print link['href']
```